# iCloud Keychain: How do I bulk import/export usernames and passwords using Windows?

Tags: windows, export, import, password-management, keychain

I would like to bulk import/export usernames and passwords to/from iCloud Keychain.

Google searches provide plenty of options (like [this one](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-import-and-export-passwords-from-icloud-keychain-1847962074)) if you have access to a Mac.

**Is there any way to do this for someone who uses Windows?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253665476

Exporting iCloud Keychain data requires an Apple computer.

The system is designed this way, and there's no currently supported method of exporting this using non-Apple computers.